# Maximum sum rectangle in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

Write a function that takes a matrix of integers and two elements of the matrix and returns the sum of the elements in the rectangle formed by the two elements. function must work in O(1) and it can use extra memory as needed. I have asked about this question in one of the interview. I scribbled a lot and could end up doing it in O(rowxCol) time. Please suggest some way out for (O1) time !!

Comment: I am not sure this can be done without loops - O(1)

Comment: Clearly only with pre-processing.

Comment: Will you please elaborate?.What type of matrix? Are the integers sequential or random...and by "two elements" you mean length and breadth of rect?

Comment: Is it the deadline for homework again?

Comment: @rajeev, Length and breadth of the sub matrix.        @@Norbert , It is not a homework . I am curious about the analogy used for O(1) time

Comment: If I read this correctly, then it is an interview question.  @SashaSalauyou comment provides the answer that the interviewer was looking for.  It is not an answer to the question you asked, which suggests that you misunderstood the question during the interview.

Answer (score 1):

Rarely I am an interviewer, and asking such questions I like to see how a candidate understands a problem, and what solutions they offer based on some assumptions--to decide, would I assign them tasks that require thinking and analyzing, or they're applicable only for monkey-coding so far.

It is obvious, that for random matrix to make some operation involving k elements those elements should be at least read, which sets lower bound of complexity to O(k). There's absolutely no doubt in that.

As an interviewer, I'd wait for clarification questions: *"May a matrix be pre-processed on building?"*, *"Are data random or follow defined structure?"*, *"Operation is performed once, or many times, allowing O(1) to be an aggregate complexity?"* and so on.

---

Returning to this particular problem, I can offer a simple solution gaining *aggregate* O(1) if operation is performed O(nm) times on the same matrix:

1. Create an aux matrix `M'` of same dimensions where each item `M'[i, j]` stores the sum of elements in original matrix `M` within a rectangle from `[0, 0]` to `[i, j]`. Such matrix is built reccurently in O(nm):

   `M'[i, j] = get(M', i - 1, j) + get(M', i, j - 1) - get(M', i - 1, j - 1) + M[i, j]`
2. When is requested the sum in rectangle from `[i1, j1]` to `[i2, j2]` in `M`, it can be easily calculated using `M'`:

   `sumRect(M, i1, j1, i2, j2) = get(M', i2, j2) 
                               - get(M', i1 - 1, j2) - get(M', i2, j1 - 1)
                               + get(M', i1 - 1, j1 - 1)`

   (here, `get(M', i, j)` returns `M'[i, j]` if `i >= 0 && j >= 0`, or `0` otherwise)
3. `sumRect` thus operates in O(1), and if it is called O(nm) times, the aggregate complexity of operation is also O(1). Additional memory consumption is O(nm).

Comment: great answer (+1) and algorithm suggestion for a somewhat vague question with not much details